# how to set up brace autocompletion in vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I want vim to autocomplete my braces, eg. when I input ( , vim should auto type ) and move the cursor to the middle of the braces automatically for me, just like all the other text editors do.
This seems easy but I haven't found a proper way. I installed YouCompleteMe but it doesn't seem to solve my problem. What can I do to get the feature I want?

Comment: [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Automatically append closing characters](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters) page on the Vim Tips Wiki. It describes some simple setups, and has a list of plugins that offer this functionality. I personally use the *AutoClose* plugin, but only occasionally, as I don't find this functionality very helpful.